# Как обрабатывать переданные ключи в bat файл?

Tags: windows, bat

Планирую запускать bat файл c разными ключами:

```
start
stop
pause
resume
install
uninstall
```

Вопрос в том что я не до конца понимаю как мне обработать эти ключи "внутри" самого батника. Можете объяснить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сохранить как test.bat или test.cmd (имя - может быть любым). Запускать с разными параметрами до полного понимания.

```
@echo off

rem %0 - имя файла как при запуске
rem %1..%9 - параметры
rem shift - сдвинуть параметры на один
rem при этом первый потеряется, но зато станет доступен десятый.

echo BAT-file name, was started as: %0
if .%1.==.. (
echo No parameters
) else (
echo First parameter is: %1
)
:repeat
shift
if .%1.==.. (
goto done
) else (
echo Next parameter is: %1
goto repeat
)
:done
echo That's all...
```